Train a decoder convolutional-based network with a non-differentiable classifier
Suppose you have a decoder network $D(\textbf{x})$ which outputs a latent representation $\textbf{z}$. My idea is to give such latent representation to a generic non-differentiable classifier $h(\textbf{z})$ and fine-tune $D$ to improve the representation for a specific task $T_h$. I was wondering how can I exploit the function $h(\textbf{z})$ to correctly fine-tune $D$.
For instance, if $h$ is a Gradient Boost Tree, I may exploit the loss function to backpropagate the decoder and skip $h$. I don't know however if this is inheritly correct, or if there is some smart, alternative way. Any suggestion?
